# Get the current subclass of the baseclass

Tags: python, exception

I am trying to create custom representation of Exception following some rules.
I want to create a base class which defines rules.

For example:

```
class MyBaseClassError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, blabla):
        super(MyBaseClassError, self).__init__(self)
        self.balbla = blabla
    def __str__(self):
        return "[{}]:{}".format(self.__subclasses()[0].__name__, self.blabla)

class ConfigFileError(MyBaseClassError):
    pass
```

So here it will return:

```
print ConfigFileError("Try again :D")
[ConfigParser]: Try again :D
```

I want to display the current subclass instead of `self.__subclasses()[0].__name__` which is the first subclass list.

Comment: So really the question is about how to get the current subclass of a class and not about making a custom `__str__` exception.  Am I understanding correct?

Comment: Sorry I changed title. At beginning my question was about `__str__` but I actually answered it in writing the post :). So my question is about subclass yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
def __str__(self):
        return "[{}]:{}".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.blabla)
```

Comment: Why complicate matters? Thank you